# TFS task integration plugin for android studio

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, tfs

This is a very generic question. Is there a TFS task plugin for android studio that would let me view/update my tasks from android stuio instead of having to go to TFS. I tried Intellij Task Integration plugin but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no this function of the plugin for android studio by now.

You can create a feature request in [UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015). The TFS Administrator team will kindly review your suggestion.

> The preview version of the Visual Studio Team Services plugin enables
>   working with Git repositories (clone, import, push and create pull
>   requests), on Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) and Team Foundation
>   Server (TFS) 2015.
>   **Announcement:**
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2015/10/23/team-foundation-plugin-for-intellij-idea.aspx
>
> **Plugin page:** http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981